# Html Table Not cloning in asp.net C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

Iam trying to create a clone of the present html table on button click but when i lat tested in Jsfiddle as a html code every thing was fine when i imported the same code to my aspx page on click the column comes and disappears am not sure what is wrong with the code need some expert advice ready to ans if clearification needed

JS:

```
 $('document').ready(function () {
        $.each($('#TimeTable_Table').find('option'), function (i, v) {
            if ($(v).val() == "  Select Subject  ") {
                $(v).prop("selected", true);
            } else {
                $(v).prop("selected", false);
            }
        });


        $("#BodyHolder_Add_New_period_button").on("click", function () {
            var newHeader = $('#TimeTable_Table thead tr').append('<th></th>');
            $('#TimeTable_Table').find('th:last()').append('Period ' + ($('#TimeTable_Table thead tr th').length + 1));
            $.each($('#TimeTable_Table tbody').find('tr'), function (i, v) {
                $(v).append($(v).find('td:last()').clone());
            });
        });
    });
```

ASPX Code

```
<div id="TimeTable_Sect" >
                    <table border="1" id="TimeTable_Table" style="       margin-left: 1%; border-collapse: collapse;   text-align: left; width:98%;">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Days
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Period 1
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                            <asp:TextBox id="tb1" runat="server" Text="Monday" readonly="true"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                     <asp:DropDownList ID="DD_Sub1" Width="150px" Height="27px"   AutoPostBack="true"
                    runat="server">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <br />
                   <asp:DropDownList ID="DD_TName1" Width="150px" Height="27px"   AutoPostBack="true"
                    runat="server">
                </asp:DropDownList>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                            <asp:TextBox id="TextBox1" runat="server" Text="Tuesday" readonly="true"  />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                 <asp:DropDownList ID="DD_Sub2" Width="150px" Height="27px"   AutoPostBack="true"
                    runat="server">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <br />
                   <asp:DropDownList ID="DD_TName2" Width="150px" Height="27px"   AutoPostBack="true"
                    runat="server">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                            <asp:TextBox id="TextBox2" runat="server" Text="Wednesday" readonly="true" />
                            </td>

                            <td>
                               <asp:DropDownList ID="DD_Sub3" Width="150px" Height="27px"   AutoPostBack="true"
                    runat="server">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <br />
                 <asp:DropDownList ID="DD_TName3" Width="150px" Height="27px"   AutoPostBack="true"
                    runat="server">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                            <asp:TextBox id="TextBox3" runat="server" Text="Thursday" readonly="true" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                 <asp:DropDownList ID="DD_Sub4" Width="150px" Height="27px"   AutoPostBack="true"
                    runat="server">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <br />
                 <asp:DropDownList ID="DD_TName4" Width="150px" Height="27px"   AutoPostBack="true"
                    runat="server">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                         <tr>
                            <td>
                            <asp:TextBox id="TextBox6" runat="server" Text="Friday" readonly="true" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                 <asp:DropDownList ID="DD_Sub5" Width="150px" Height="27px"   AutoPostBack="true"
                    runat="server">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <br />
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DD_TName5" Width="150px" Height="27px"   AutoPostBack="true"
                    runat="server">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                            <asp:TextBox id="TextBox4" runat="server" Text="Saturday" readonly="true" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                               <asp:DropDownList ID="DD_Sub6" Width="150px" Height="27px"   AutoPostBack="true"
                    runat="server">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <br />
                 <asp:DropDownList ID="DD_TName6" Width="150px" Height="27px"   AutoPostBack="true"
                    runat="server">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                            <asp:TextBox id="TextBox5" runat="server" Text="Sunday" readonly="true"/>
                            </td>
                             <td>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="DD_Sub7" Width="150px" Height="27px"   AutoPostBack="true"
                    runat="server">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <br />
                 <asp:DropDownList ID="DD_TName7" Width="150px" Height="27px"   AutoPostBack="true"
                    runat="server">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div id="Add_New_period">
                <asp:Button id="Add_New_period_button" Text="Add Period" runat="server" />
                </div>
```

Comment: can you supply the link to the fiddle?